# How to upload a large file (~10GB) into Azure Blob Storage directly from Browser, using PUT with SaS Url?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The scenario is simple:
My webapp is composed of ReactJS SPA as frontend, and web api running in VM as backend;
When user need to upload file, the backend generates a URL with SAS token for uploading file into an azure storage account and Blob container. The backend replies to the frontend SPA with this url, and the user can directly upload file from the local browser to azure blob storage directly, without needing to go cross the backend VM again.

In the backend, I use this code to generate the url with SAS token:

```
function generate_signed_url(BLOB_NAME, AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY) {
    
    const ACCOUNT_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    const CONTAINER_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME;
    const ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY;

    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName=ACCOUNT_NAME, accountKey=ACCESS_KEY)
      
    //This URL will be valid for 1 hour
    const expDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000);

    // Generate service level SAS for a blob
    const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      containerName: CONTAINER_NAME, // Required
      blobName: BLOB_NAME, // Required
      permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"), // Required
      startsOn: new Date(), // Optional
      expiresOn: expDate, // Required. Date type
      cacheControl: "cache-control-override", // Optional
      contentDisposition: "content-disposition-override", // Optional
      contentEncoding: "content-encoding-override", // Optional
      contentLanguage: "content-language-override", // Optional
      contentType: "content-type-override", // Optional
      ipRange: { start: "0.0.0.0", end: "255.255.255.255" }, // Optional
      protocol: SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp, // Optional
      version: "2016-05-31" // Optional
    },
    sharedKeyCredential 
    ).toString();

    SaSURL = `https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${AZURE_CONTAINER}/${AZURE_BLOB}?${containerSAS}`;
    
    console.log(`SAS URL for blob is: ${SaSURL}`);
    return SaSURL;
}
```

In the frontend SPA, I use this code to upload file with the SaS Url:

```
      await axios({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: SaSUrl,
        data: file,
        signal: axiosUploadController.signal
      });
```

However, I'm getting a 413 error:

```
PUT https://johnapp.blob.core.windows.net/appFiles/raw/largeOne-4GB.zip?sv=2016-05-31&spr=https%2Chttp&st=2023-07-12T16%3A28%3A48Z&se=2023-07-12T17%3A28%3A48Z&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=123qwse123qwe%3D&rscc=cache-control-override&rscd=content-disposition-override&rsce=content-encoding-override&rscl=content-language-override&rsct=content-type-override 413 (The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.)
```

It turns out there is a limit to the single PUT operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad#remarks
and the limit is 5000Mb, or 4000Mb;

So, how can I upload this 10GB zip file with the SaS Url then? I need to provide service for my customers to upload much bigger files in future ( ~20GB );

Answer (score 1):

To upload large blob, you would need to break the blob in chunks (also called blocks) and upload those chunks using [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block?tabs=azure-ad). Once you have uploaded all chunks, you would then need to commit those chunks using [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list?tabs=azure-ad).

I wrote a blog post about it long time back that you may find useful: https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/.

Please note that I wrote this post before JavaScript SDK was there. Do check out the Azure Blob Storage JavaScript SDK as it already has implementations for the Put Block and Put Block List REST API operations.