# Azure Storage Copy Blob From Url (REST API) error on x-ms-requires-sync header

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a large file (public accessable over the internet) to an Azure blob using the PUT REST API with the x-ms-copy-source header.
The PUT uri includes a SAS token and I use these headers:

```
x-ms-version: 2023-11-03
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-copy-source: https://mypublicfile/filename.csv
```

That works fine. But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url) states that also the x-ms-requires-sync:true headers should be added and is required. But when I add this, I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:935f1ff5-a01e-0065-6f34-80e89b000000
Time:2024-03-27T10:51:11.7886167Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>x-ms-requires-sync</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>true</HeaderValue>
</Error>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Beside this, is there any size limit (beside the obvious max blob sizes stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/scalability-targets#scale-targets-for-blob-storage)).
Up to 5GiB seems to work fine, but large files give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.</Message>
> <HeaderName>x-ms-requires-sync</HeaderName>
> <HeaderValue>true</HeaderValue> </Error>
> ```

The above error indicates that the **`x-ms-requires-sync`** header is not required for copying blobs from a URL. This header is used to specify whether the copy operation should be synchronous.

Copy blob operations are asynchronous by default. Therefore, you can remove the **`x-ms-requires-sync`** header from your request.

Hence, I also tried without **`x-ms-requires-sync`** in my request, and it executed successfully.

**Postman:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Regarding your second question.the Maximum blob size via single write operation" is `5000MiB`.
If you need to upload a larger blob, you can break it up into smaller blocks or chunks and upload them in parallel.

You can use the [Put block from url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-from-url?tabs=microsoft-entra-id) request to upload large files that will break blobs into chunks and upload the chunks using the request. You would then need to commit those chunks using [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list?tabs=microsoft-entra-id) after you have uploaded all of them.

**Reference:**

[How to upload a large file (~10GB) into Azure Blob Storage directly from Browser, using PUT with SaS Url? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672924/how-to-upload-a-large-file-10gb-into-azure-blob-storage-directly-from-browser/76673252#76673252) by Gaurav Mantri.

Comment: I have managed to upload files this way up to 5GiB. So I don't understand the max of 256 MiB. Does this perhaps apply when you upload the file in the request body itself and not in this case where you supply just an source url? Perhaps Azure does the heavy lifting on the service side in this case?

Comment: You are correct! 256 MB limit applies when you upload the file in the request body itself. When you use the x-ms-copy-source header to copy a file from a public URL, Azure Storage service retrieves the file from the source URL and stores it in the blob storage. Therefore, the size of the file that you can copy using this method is not limited by the 256 MiB limit. In this case, Azure Storage service does the heavy lifting on the service side, as you mentioned. The service retrieves the file from the source URL and stores it in the blob storage, so you don't need to worry about the size limit.

Comment: Updated in answer also.

Comment: I toke another closer look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/scalability-targets#scale-targets-for-blob-storage) page and now I see in the second table that the "Maximum blob size via single write operation" is 5000MiB. So that explains IMO the limit of GiB I experience. Perhaps you can add this to your answer @Venkatesan, than I will accept your answer.

Comment: Updated in answer.